# SWT that changes label color is crashing

Tags: java, swt

ColorDetector.java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;

import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;



public class ColorDetector {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        Display display = new Display();
        //Display starts everything
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();

        shell.setLayout(gridLayout);

        Label label = new Label(shell, 0);

        label.setText("WHAT COLOR AM I");

        Refresher ref = new Refresher(display, label);
        ref.start();



        shell.open();

        System.out.println("Shell started");

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                          display.sleep();
                }

    }



    }
}
```

Refresher.java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;

import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;

public class Refresher extends Thread {

    static Display d;

    static Label l;


    public Refresher(Display display, Label label) {
        Refresher.d = display;
        Refresher.l = label;
    }

    private static void colorUpdater(Display display, Label label) {
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Robot colorGet = null;
                try {
                    colorGet = new Robot();
                } catch (AWTException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                java.awt.Color awtColor = colorGet.getPixelColor(0, 700);
                Color color = new Color(display, awtColor.getRed(), awtColor.getGreen(), awtColor.getBlue());

                label.setForeground(color); 
            }
        });
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Refresher started");
        while (true) {
            colorUpdater(d, l);
        }
    }


}
```

The above code is supposed to create a window that has a label. This label is taken by Refresher.java and is repeatedly changed to the color of a certain pixel (0,500) of my screen (which is where I put a Google Chrome color picker tab). The goal was to be able to dynamically change the color of the label by changing the color of the pixel at (0, 500). The application runs fine for a few seconds but then crashes and gives me this.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000010971a4d5, pid=11999, tid=46339
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (12.0.1+12) (build 12.0.1+12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, bsd-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.dylib+0x31a4d5]  _ZN20G1ParScanThreadState22copy_to_survivor_spaceE11InCSetStateP7oopDescP11markOopDesc+0xe1
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/myname/eclipse-workspace/Screen Color Detector/hs_err_pid11999.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/0upjvApd) is the error report file

Comment: A crash like that is caused by a bug in the JDK native code, try a newer version of Java.

Comment: @greg-449 that worked, thank you! Why is it that Java 12 can't handle my code?

Comment: Most probably it is just a bug in the JVM code that is fixed in the newer version

Comment: @greg-449 This seems to have only been a temporary solution. The same error is appearing again

Comment: it is still a bug in the JVM/AWT/SWT native code. I would think that mixing SWT with the AWT Robot class is not helping as mixing graphics toolkits often causes issues. There are ways of capturing the screen available in SWT - see for example [this](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet215.java)